# Default Pages for new Spaces in Confluence

Tags: wiki, spaces, confluence

Does anyone know, if it is possible to prepopulate new Confluence Spaces with specific Pages? What I want to have when creating a new Space is the following default structure:

```
Home
|_ Category A
|_ Category B
|_ Category C
|_ Category D
```

I read the documentation about Global Templates and Space Templates, but it seems, that it is just possible to edit the default content of the Home Page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way is to use the Copy Space Plugin - We've created a space as a blueprint for our projects https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/212

Comment: This plugin is no longer supported and only works with Confluence versions up to 5.9.14.

Answer (score 3):

I am creating my spaces along with a skeleton of default pages using an excellent **CLI plugin** (written by Bob Swift):

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.swift.confluence.cli/cloud/overview

Answer (score 1):

As the Copy Space Plugin is no longer supported the best alternative I could find was the Copy Space Tree plugin by Artemis Software: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.nurago.confluence.plugins.treecopy/cloud/overview

It does also allow you to copy across attachments and copy trees within a space to itself while keeping the names unique although I have not personally found any use for this feature yet.